# AlertDialog from service in any part of app

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app and I start my app with MyApp.java where I declare everything and it is my starting point of app.
In `onCreate()`, I start a service with intent.

I also create an instance of service and try to access the service object inside countdown timer `onFinish()` as -

```
MYService myService = new MYService();
myService.getDialog();
```

And in MYService, I have this method as -

```
public void showMsg(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplication())
                .setTitle("Success!")
                .setMessage("Countdown")
                .setPositiveButton("Success", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                }).create();

        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

My Goal is whichever part of app I am in like whichever activity or fragment, I must be able to get this alertdialog after 5 seconds of countdown timer.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BoundService`:

1. Create a core Activity such that any Activity in your app extend core activity.
2. Bind this core Activity to service you have created.
3. Whenever time completes or timer expires, send message to core Activity.
4. When Activity gets a message, It will show your dialog.

You can refer this [example](http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/) here.

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<service
    android:name=".ShowAlertService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

In your MainActivity.JAVA

```
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowAlertService.class);
        startService(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // This registers mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                .registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter("broadcastMsg"));
    }

    // Handling the received Intents for the "my-integer" event
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                   if(intent.getBooleanExtra("showalert",false))
                   {
                       showMsg();
                   }


        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Unregister since the activity is not visible
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                .unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void showMsg(){
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Success!")
                .setMessage("Countdown")
                .setPositiveButton("Success", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

and at last your service class will be like

```
   import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ShowAlertService extends Service {

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    String TAG = "Timers";
    int Your_X_SECS = 5;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startTimer();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        stoptimertask();
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    //we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
    final Handler handler = new Handler();


    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, Your_X_SECS * 1000); //
        //timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000,1000); //
    }

    public void stoptimertask() {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            sendMessage();

                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    //Send message to activity
    private void sendMessage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("broadcastMsg");
        intent.putExtra("showalert",true);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

Send Broadcast message "showalert" to activity and display alert as soon as you get the broadcast message.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela look at this snippet from service class   `  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.activity)`

Comment: I'm taking this instance and checking that static value whether it is null or not. It is not coming under best practise but it works.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I personally compiled this code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Ok. but personally it is very poor coding and should not be suggested.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela sorry for that. I am removing this spippets

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Sir I've done changes is it good? I've send broadcasted message to activity and displaying the alert. Reply if I've done kind of mistake somewhere.